# Angular error when changing font color from API value

Tags: angular

I have the following line of code in my `dash.component.html`:

```html
<mat-card-title [ngStyle]="{'color': offlineOnline.value <= 4 ? '#e74c3c' : '#2ecc71'}">THINGY</mat-card-title>
```

The offlineOnline calls a webapi service and returns one json object in the following form:

```
{"tagname":"mytag", "value":"99"}
```

I have a class called `myClass` which has:

```js
export class myClass{
    tagname: string;
    value: number;
}
```

Within `dash.component.ts` i have the following:

```js
offlineOnline:myClass;

ngOnInit() {

this._myapi.getonoffli()
    .subscribe
    (
      data=>
      {
         this.offlineOnline = data;
      }
    )
```

which calls the following in `myapi.services.ts`

```js
getonoffline():Observable<myClass>{
        return this.httpclient.get<myClass>(this.myUrl+ "mytagname").pipe(map(res => new myClass(res)));
    }
```

All the above works, the colour of the `mat-card-title` text changes depending on the value returned, but.....

I see the following error in my console which relates to this line therefore I must be doing something wrong and I would like to know what.

[image: picture of console error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all one color is show every time because you used ternary operator `If True:#e74c3c/ False:#2ecc71`. Second one your DOM is load first but it's not getting variable value which is you use in ternary operator. for priority follow this https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks.
or you can remove this error this way.

One: Check `offlineOnline` in ternary operator.

```
<mat-card-title [ngStyle]="{'color': offlineOnline?.value <= 4 ? '#e74c3c' : '#2ecc71'}">THINGY</mat-card-title>
```

Second: Check if get `offlineOnline` than create `mat-card-title` create in DOM.

```
<mat-card-title *ngIf="offlineOnline"
[ngStyle]="{'color': offlineOnline.value <= 4 ? '#e74c3c' : '#2ecc71'}">
    THINGY
</mat-card-title>
```

Comment: You sir are a superstar.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend redoing this a slightly bit and not subscribing to observable in component directly, instead, assign observable to a variable:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dash',
    templateUrl: './dash.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dash.component.css']
})
export class DashComponent {
    public offlineOnline$: Observable<myClass>;

    constructor(private readonly _myapi: MyApiService) {
        this.offlineOnline$ = this._myapi.getonoffli();
    }
}
```

This will let Angular manage subscriptions and will prevent memory leaks.
Next rewrite component as follows:

```html
<mat-card-title *ngIf="offlineOnline$ | async as offlineOnline" [ngStyle]="{'color': offlineOnline.value <= 4 ? '#e74c3c' : '#2ecc71'}">
    THINGY
</mat-card-title>
```

Using `async` piple you'll show card only when value has been received from API.

Also, your API data is sketchy, while your class has it as an integer, API brings it back as a string, make sure that you get a number, not a string and that you compare numbers to numbers in code.

Comment: HI, thanks for the reponse however it doesnt work.  I no longer get errors in my console but the page is blank and no data is displayed.